# CasperJS Waiting for live DOM to populate

Tags: angularjs, backbone.js, casperjs

I'm evaluating using Casper.js to do functional/acceptance testing for my app. The biggest problem I've seen so far is that my app is an SPA that uses handlebars templates (which are compiled to JS) The pages of my app are nothing more than a shell with an empty div where the markup will be injected via JS.

I've messed around with Casper a little and tried using its waitFor functions. All I can seem to get from it are my main empty page before any of the markup is injected. I've tried waitForSelector but it just times out after 5 seconds. Should I try increasing the timeout? The page typically loads in a browser very quickly, so it seems like there may be another issue.

I'm using Yadda along with Casper for step definitions:

```
module.exports.init = function() {
    var dictionary = new Dictionary()
        .define('LOCALE', /(fr|es|ie)/)
        .define('NUM', /(\d+)/);

    var tiles;

    function getTiles() {
        return document.querySelectorAll('.m-product-tile');
    }

    function getFirstTile(collection) {
        return Array.prototype.slice.call(collection)[0];
    }

    var library = English.library(dictionary)

        .given('product tiles', function() {
            casper.open('http://www.example.com/#/search?keywords=ipods&resultIndex=1&resultsPerPage=24');
            casper.then(function() {
                // casper.capture('test.png');
                casper.echo(casper.getHTML());
                casper.waitForSelector('.m-product-tile', function() {
                    tiles = getTiles();
                });
            });
        })

        .when('I tap a tile', function() {
            casper.then(function() {
                casper.echo(tiles); //nodelist
                var tile = Array.prototype.slice.call(tiles)[0];
                casper.echo(tile); //undefined!
                var pid = tile.getAttribute('data-pid');
            })
        })

        .then('I am taken to a product page', function() {

        });

    return library;
};
```

Any Angular, Backbone, Ember folks running into issues like this?

Comment: Register the to [`remote.message`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#remote-message) and [`page.error`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#page-error) events. Maybe there are errors. If `bind` is an issue, you need a [shim](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/10522#issuecomment-39248521).

Comment: You might want to change `open` to `thenOpen` inside the `given` block if you want to invoke `init` multiple times in the same script.

Comment: Yep, looks like I'm seeing the error with bind being undefined. I'll give the shim a shot. Thanks!

Comment: I see the same thing for pages expecting any kind of dynamic population from on-page scripts. Nothing I've tried works...